# How to hide edit tab on entity form

Tags: entities

I'd like to remove the ability to edit/update an entity form once it was been completed and submitted correctly.

I thought there might be a way to lock an entity form? Or remove access? or hide the edit tab.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could look into hiding the tab using [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). If you set access callback to FALSE then it will be hidden.